# Can a Kafka consumer be a producer on the same kafka group

Tags: apache-kafka, taskmanager

I'd like to use Kafka as a task scheduler. Here is an example:

Let's say I want my service to periodically download the most recent tweets from a given set of accounts.

Producers: when new twitter handle to be extracted is added to the service, the producer pushes this message to Kafka:

{ twitter_user: "new_user_handle", start_at: "current_timestamp"}

Consumers: each in an infinite loop:

```
1. receive a task from Kafka: say {"elon_musk", "2021-11-29-22:55"}
2. extract all the tweets of user @elon_musk" since 2021-11-29-22:55.
3. produce a new message {"elon_musk", "<timestamp-of-latest-tweet-just-extracted>"}
4. Commit
```

Of course, ideally steps 3 and 4 should execute in a single "transaction". That way the next consumer worker will pick up where this consumer finished.

Is this possible with Kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consumers and producers are independent processes. There is nothing preventing you from producing data that a consumer will poll.

If you are consuming data from existing topics, then filtering/extracting data to populate a new topic, then that is the use-case for Kafka Streams & KSQL.

Comment: Can I transactionally commit in the consumer and produce a new message?

Comment: Should be possible to call `commitSync()`, yes. However, that'll effectively skip messages if you commit and then the producer fails. I suggest you use Kafka Streams if you are producing back to the same cluster